# Is there a way to hide just the version number, but leave the generator tag?

Tags: wordpress-theming

Is there a way to hide the version of WordPress being used, but *only* the version number? Specifically, I'd prefer the tag read

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress" />
```

instead of

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.9" />
```

I know of the correct way to remove it altogether, but I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the correct way to remove it altogether and then add a new generator tag?

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
add_action('wp_head', 'my_wp_generator');
function my_wp_generator() {
    echo '<meta name="generator" content="WordPress" />';
}
```